# bootstrap container doesn't center when child of absolute

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a parent div with `position: absolute;` having this means my child div the bootstrap `class="container"` doesn't float in the center of the page instead it just sits to the left. I want the container class to act as it should, in this case center my content.

```
<section id="portfolio">
    <div class="container">
        Content
    </div>
</section>

/*display content below the fold*/
#portfolio{
    position: absolute;
    top:120%;
}
```

Comment: No your real Question is: __Why is bootstrap unable to read my mind__? Maybe you should tell your content to be centered? http://www.w3schools.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `width:100%` to your #portfolio CSS selector:

```css
/*display content below the fold*/
#portfolio{
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top:120%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<section id="portfolio">
    <div class="container">
        Content
    </div>
</section>
```

The above code snippet will center the container within #portfolio without centering the text. By default, Bootstrap 3 containers are fixed width and centered within their parent containers using `margin-left: auto;` and `margin-right: auto`. If you also want to center the text within the container you can add `text-align: center`

Comment: That fixed it thank you, I couldn't figure it out for the life of me. :)

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you expected?

```css
#portfolio {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<section id="portfolio">
  <div class="container">
    Content
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: is snippet working with other langs, too? leave a comment @LittleByBlue

Comment: you used `snippet` to make the example runnable: Could I do this with ruby, for example, too?

Comment: No.  HTML, CSS & JS only. @LittleByBlue